# WebBrowser Control and GetElement by ID

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, getelementbyid

I am using Visual C# Winforms to control a WebBrowser object.

Specifically I want to use WebBrowser.Document.GetObjectByID("myid").Style to set the style of an object that is part of the document loaded into the WebBrowser object.

I want to have button on the WinForm toggle the Style of a heading from "display:none" to "display:block;text-align:middle".
This is what I am doing:

```
private void frmView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string question = "How many cows?";
string answer = "5 cows";
webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(false);
webBrowser1.Document.Write("<html><body><div id='question'><h1>");
webBrowser1.Document.Write(question);
webBrowser1.Document.Write("</h1></div><div id='answer'><h2>");
webBrowser1.Document.Write(answer);
webBrowser1.Document.Write("</h2></div></body></html>");
webBrowser1.Refresh();
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("answer").Style = "display:none;";
//if I do a breakpoint here, I get the Style = "DISPLAY:NONE"
btnAnswer.Visible = true;
btnNext.Visible = true;
}

private void btnAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//if this is the first time ran, doing a breakpoint here will
//show Style to be NULL
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("answer").Style = "display:block;text-align:center";
//now the Style is properly set, and will remain that way, even after this function returns}
```

Note that I am able to control the Style property with the btnAnswer_Click method, but not with the frmView_Load method. I know I can just put the style info into div tag when I create it (this does work), but why doesn't the code above work?

Update:
I found something that may be going in the right direction. If I call `webBrowser1.Update()` at any point after `webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank")` everything in frmView_Load works. Unfortunately, any attempts to change the document after frmView_Load exits will fail. Not only will they fail, but after frmView_Load returns webBrowser1.Document will be set to NULL somehow.
Can anyone shed some light on how this control is supposed to work?

Comment: Which `WebBrowser` control are you using? Windows Forms? WPF?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Comment: Your question is a bit convoluted, I tried the code and clicking a button on the form (its not a <input button> is it?) changes the answer to white or black. The other thing that differs for me is "after I exit that function  the .Style property it is null", the style was set for me. Can you edit your question to have a FormLoad event setting initial HTML and have a button_click event to change the colour, that way its going to be easy for everyone to repro.

Comment: I've updated my question to show more. The unexpected behavior is that I can set the style in my form_Load, but that style is somehow dropped after form_Load exits. If I press btnAnswer it shows the style as "NULL", but after (even after it returns, or is re-called), it shows a correctly set style.

Comment: @JeremyThompson If I use a button to modify the style, it works. But, as you can see in the new code I posted, for whatever reason the FormLoad method doesn't permanently set the style. I think there is some kind of "finalize" command that I'm not sending after I initialize the page, which automatically happens after the initializing function. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the MS Documentation on the WebBrowser control, I realize that everything the browser does is asynchronous. Having said that, it means that I have to block my control threads after setting properties in order to ensure those properties have been set.

Basically, my "write" to the document isn't done just because the "write" function returns. I have to block the control thread till the document reflects those changes if I want to reference the contents of that write. MS recommends a sleep loop. Here's what my write & block function looks like:

```
private void ChangeDocument(string documentText, double timeout)
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    double elapsed = 0;

    if (webBrowser1.Document == null)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
    }

    webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(false);

    while ((webBrowser1.DocumentText != "") && (elapsed < timeout))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        elapsed = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    webBrowser1.Document.Write(documentText);

    startTime = DateTime.Now;
    elapsed = 0;

    while ((webBrowser1.DocumentText != documentText) && (elapsed < timeout))
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        elapsed = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your responses everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your hidden text in a `<div>` with the `display:none` style? When you need to show it, you'd just need to update the [`display`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) style. You can also apply this style to the `h2` element that contains your answer in your sample code.

Comment: Well, I tried your suggestion, but the effect is the same as what I'm doing right now. I was originally applying the style to the H2 element, but now I'm using the DIV. I think I may be missing some kind of event trigger. If I make a second button to only set the style, it works. But if I use the same function to create the HTML *and* modify the style, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Im not really familiar with this stuff but I would have thought that you need to call

```
webBrowser1.Refresh();
```

at the very end of frmView_Load

Comment: Tried this also, there is no difference. Also, the btnAnswer_Click method does not call a refresh, and it is able to update the style without issue.